# Why does implementing WPF DragDrop behaviour stop ListBoxItems becoming selected on the first click?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, selection, listboxitem

I have been implementing basic drag and drop functionality using WPF and C# quite successfully for some time now. I have always had one problem after implementing it though... for some reason, the drag and drop functionality stops the `ListBoxItem`s from becoming selected (on the first click).

If I click on a `ListBoxItem` but don't drag it, it doesn't get selected and the drag icon appears momentarily. On the next click I can then select any of the `ListBoxItem`s and the drag icon does not appear. This cycle then repeats... first click won't select, second one will.

Below is a typical implementation of my drag and drop code, taken from the Micorsoft MCTS 70-511 'Training kit' book.

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    object data = (ListBoxItem)(FrameworkElement)sender;
    if (data != null) DragDrop.DoDragDrop(ListBox, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    e.Handled = false;
}

private void ListBox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListBoxItem))) e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListBoxItem));
    if (data != null) DoSomethingWith((DataType)((ListBoxItem)data).DataContext);
}
```

The drag and drop works fine, but the item selection doesn't... I presumed that by adding `e.Handled = false` in the `ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` handler, the `ListBoxItem` selection mechanism could handle the click event, but it never reaches that far.

I also tried handling the drag initiation in the `MouseLeftButtonDown` handler instaed of the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` handler, but the `ListBoxItem` selection mechanism handles the click event and it never reached that drag drop handler.

There must be a way to initiate the drag drop operation and still have the `ListBoxItem` that was clicked on become selected, but I still haven't managed to find it... any clues anyone?

UPDATE >>>

Thanks to the MSDN article @icebat provided a link for, I've managed to get the drag and drop functionality working perfectly. It is now as follows:

```
private void SourceListBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        object data = ((ListBox)(FrameworkElement)sender).SelectedItem;
        if (data != null) 
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(SourceListBox, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}

private void TargetListBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(DragObject))) e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void TargetListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragObject));
    if (data != null) DoSomethingWith((DragObject)data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `MouseMove` event instead of MouseDown for drag and drop. You can find more information and some code in the [Drag and Drop article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx#Implementing_Drag_And_Drop) on MSDN.